Appium Calculator Example: No route found for //session
I'm new to appium and looking to try a simple example running against the Windows calculator.  I have appium2 running and installed the Windows driver.  I see a number of other posts that indicate adding a "/wd/hub" but as far as I can tell that shouldn't be required for Appium 2.
This is the error I keep getting when my python client attempts to connect:
Appium
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v2.11.4
[Appium] The autodetected Appium home path: C:\Users\hugfos\.appium
[Appium] Attempting to load driver windows...
[Appium] Requiring driver at C:\Users\hugfos\.appium\node_modules\appium-windows-driver\build\index.js
[Appium] WindowsDriver has been successfully loaded in 0.070s
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://0.0.0.0:4723
[Appium] You can provide the following URLs in your client code to connect to this server:
        http://172.24.40.154:4723/
        http://127.0.0.1:4723/ (only accessible from the same host)
        http://172.18.144.1:4723/
        http://172.19.176.1:4723/
[Appium] Available drivers:
[Appium]   - windows@2.12.32 (automationName 'Windows')
[Appium] No plugins have been installed. Use the "appium plugin" command to install the one(s) you want to use.
[HTTP] Request idempotency key: 914f40d9-a010-4b37-bdee-be38facee47b
[HTTP] --> POST //session {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"windows","appium:options":{"automationName":"Windows","deviceName":"WindowsPC","app":"Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"}}}}
[HTTP] No route found for //session
[HTTP] <-- POST //session 404 7 ms - 211

I see this error on the python side:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
My Python code looks like this:
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.common import AppiumOptions
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

appium_server_url = "http://172.24.40.154:4723/"

capabilities = {
    "platformName":"windows",
    "appium:options": {
        "automationName":"Windows",
        "deviceName":"WindowsPC",
        "app":"Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
        }
    }

options = AppiumOptions().load_capabilities(capabilities)
driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=options)
driver.find_element_by_name("One").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("Plus").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("Seven").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("Equals").click()
driver.quit()

How can I fix the error:  No route found for //session?
